# how to access a textbox in a grid in a stackpanel

Tags: c#, xaml

I have the following code:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentStackPanel">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Min Value" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding MinValue}" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Max Value" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding MinValue}" />
            </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to add a button so that I can clear the text in both TextBoxes.  This code doesn't work

```
        private void ClearAllClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             foreach (TextBox tb in ContentStack.Children)
             {
                 tb.Text = String.Empty;
             }
        }
```

how do I access the textbox inside the grid of ContentStackPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Children` property only gives you immediate children, not all descendants.  You could write a helper method to traverse the tree:

```
private void ClearAllClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ClearTextChildren(ContentStackPanel);
}

private void ClearTextChildren((Panel container)
{
    foreach (var element in container.Children)
    {
        if (element is TextBox)
            ((TextBox)element).Text = String.Empty;
        else if (element is Panel)
            ClearChildren((Panel)element);
    }
}
```

---

An alternative approach (probably better, since it's fragile to traverse UI trees in code) would be to use a `Command` implementation on the button, instead of a click handler.  This will allow you to clear the view-model properties instead of the text boxes themselves.

```
<Button x:Name="ClearAll" Command="{Binding ClearAllCommand}" />
```

"ClearAllCommand" should be in the same place as "MinValue" and "MaxValue":

```
public ICommand ClearAllCommand { get; private set; }
```

Using a [standard `DelegateCommand` implementation](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html):

```
ClearAllCommand = new DelegateCommand(arg => {
    MinValue = null;
    MaxValue = null; 
});
```

Comment: this is not working for textboxes inside a grid in the panel. Can you help me to access the values of a textbox which is inside a grid in a panel??